# UITableView crashes when the same row is selected twice

Tags: ios, ios4, uitableview

When i run the app and select a row it passes some information to EmployeeInfoPage and works fine. When i hit back and then select the same row. It crashes at the line tableController.empInfo = employee;. I get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS error

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{   
EmployeeInfoTableView *tableController = [[EmployeeInfoTableView alloc] init];

NSDictionary *employee = [[self.orderedSections valueForKey:[[[self.orderedSections allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)] objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

tableController.empInfo = employee;    

[self.navigationController pushViewController:tableController animated:YES];    

[tableController release];
}
```

This is the EmployeeInfoTableView.h file

```
@interface EmployeeInfoTableView : UITableViewController <UIActionSheetDelegate , MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate, MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate>{

    NSDictionary *empInfo;
    NSString *currentPhoneNumber;
    NSString *currentEmail;

    UIActionSheet *callConfirm;
}
```

Then i use empInfo to set certain fields in the tableview.

This is my dealloc method

```
- (void)dealloc{
    [super dealloc];
    [empInfo dealloc];
    [currentEmail dealloc];
    [currentPhoneNumber dealloc];
    [callConfirm dealloc];
}
```

Is my error becuase i need to release any of my objects?

This is the error i got from off my iPhone, i really have no idea how to read this.

```
  Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0xb001fb49
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x31798c98 objc_msgSend + 16
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x317a24d2 objc_setProperty_non_gc + 62
2   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3179a040 objc_setProperty + 20
3   CorporateDirectory              0x0000e5f0 0x1000 + 54768
4   CorporateDirectory              0x00003ac2 0x1000 + 10946
5   UIKit                           0x32cc3514 -[UITableView                                         _selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:notifyDelegate:] + 656
6   UIKit                           0x32d270e4 -[UITableView _userSelectRowAtPendingSelectionIndexPath:] + 124
7   Foundation                      0x338266ce __NSFireDelayedPerform + 362
8   CoreFoundation                  0x345f4a40     __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 8
9   CoreFoundation                  0x345f6ec4 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 844
10  CoreFoundation                  0x345f783e __CFRunLoopRun + 1082
11  CoreFoundation                  0x34587ebc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
12  CoreFoundation                  0x34587dc4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
13  GraphicsServices                0x322b2418 GSEventRunModal + 108
14  GraphicsServices                0x322b24c4 GSEventRun + 56
15  UIKit                           0x32c9dd62 -[UIApplication _run] + 398
16  UIKit                           0x32c9b800 UIApplicationMain + 664
17  CorporateDirectory              0x00002a52 0x1000 + 6738
18  CorporateDirectory              0x00002a10 0x1000 + 6672




Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x339663ec __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3480f6d8 _pthread_wqthread + 592
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3480fbbc start_wqthread + 0

Thread 2 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x33966fbc kevent + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x322df032 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 706
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x322e003a _dispatch_queue_invoke + 86
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x322df5ea _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 186
4   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3480f58a _pthread_wqthread + 258
5   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3480fbbc start_wqthread + 0

Thread 3 name:  WebThread
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x33963c00 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x33963758 mach_msg + 44
2   CoreFoundation                  0x345f52b8 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 88
3   CoreFoundation                  0x345f7562 __CFRunLoopRun + 350
4   CoreFoundation                  0x34587ebc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
5   CoreFoundation                  0x34587dc4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
6   WebCore                         0x3666927e _ZL12RunWebThreadPv + 382
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3480e30a _pthread_start + 242
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3480fbb4 thread_start + 0

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
r0: 0x0016c020    r1: 0x32f63814      r2: 0x000000a8      r3: 0x0016c020
r4: 0xb001fb41    r5: 0x00000000      r6: 0x001eeca8      r7: 0x2fdfe8c4
r8: 0x00a1da00    r9: 0x0016c020     r10: 0x00000003     r11: 0x00161a50
ip: 0x00000000    sp: 0x2fdfe8a4      lr: 0x317a24d9      pc: 0x31798c98
```

cpsr: 0x00000030

Comment: What's this `CorporateDirectory` class of yours do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try by removing this line

```
[tableController release];
```

from your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method. The `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error is thrown when we try to access a variable that was released previously. You're simultaneously releasing `NSDictionary *employee` object with `tableController`.

EDIT: To prevent your dictionary from being released, you can `copy` the required contents of the dictionary as `tableController.empInfo = [employee copy];` and then release `tableController` which would suit this situation best.

Comment: That fixed it thanks. so i am still a little confused as to why realeasing it was causing that error. I was releasing it so that i could reuse it, but from what i understand i don't need to release it because i will just be calling it again if they click another row. Is that assumption correct?

Comment: Releasing objects is a good habit but we have to take care. `[tableController release];` is something we should do to ensure memory is not being wasted. Unfortunately, in your case, you were inadvertently releasing memory of an object that you had to use later. One way out of this is to use `autorelease`. Another is to `copy` the contents of your object into `employee`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see anything wrong with your didSelectRowAtIndexPath but your dealloc method is certainly not right. **Never** call dealloc in your code (i.e. only release the object when you're done with them).

Your dealloc method should look like this:

```
- (void)dealloc{
    [empInfo release];
    [currentEmail release];
    [currentPhoneNumber release];
    [callConfirm release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: WHat is the difference if super dealloc is at the beginning or end of the list?

Comment: I'm not sure if there is any different, but isn't it logical to put it at the end, to make sure all the properties have the chance to release, since this object is going away after the call. Similarly I always put [super viewDidLoad] or [super loadView] at the beginning to make sure the view is properly set up before I modify anything.

Comment: +1 Because this is the real reason for the crash. When the EmployeeInfoTableView gets deallocated it will force-deallocate its empInfo object. And this object is used by the parent tableView. The other answer creates a leak to cover a horrible bug. I bet zach never tried the autorelease, because that would crash too.

Comment: @MatthiasBauch true...a better way would be to `copy` the contents into `empInfo` and release it there and then. Even if `[empInfo release];` is not called in `dealloc`, this code would crash because `empInfo` would be released anyway. I've edited my answer to incorporate the same.

Comment: @MatthiasBauch PS: I had already mentioned the *real reason* in my answer...the solution wasn't the best, though...